# Magento redirecting AWS Load Balancer

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing

Good afternoon,

I have a Magento installation with Nginx running on an Auto Scaling Group on AWS with a standard 3 instances. To redirect traffic I use a load balancer with SSL causing my structure looks as follows:

User> Load Balancer (Port 443)> Instance (Port 80)

I changed into my database in the table mg_core_config_data the URLs to use https.

The problem I think is happening is the following:

Every time I access my URL, Load Balancer attempts to fetch the bodies content to send me the information I am requesting, in this way, as I am using port 80, when the Load Balancer reaches my instance and attempts to load the Magento, the base_url that is in the database redirects to https. With this redirection, the process is repeated again because I'm redirected back to https: // and try to get the instance information on port 80 again. I think that every problem is among this base_url and I can not return the magento information with port 80.

Follow my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 DEFAULT_SERVER;

    server_name _;
    root /home/ubuntu/www/mysite;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $ uri $ uri / /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \ .php $ {
        try_files $ uri /index.php = 404;
        fastcgi_pass unix: /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $ document_root $ fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_params include;
        fastcgi_cache CACHE;
        fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $ no_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $ no_cache;
    }

    ...
}
```

The error I'm getting accessing my load balancer via https:

[image]

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions or have been through this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your description, the problem is that your instances believe they're accessed over HTTP (not HTTPS) and are redirecting to HTTPS.

This is not an ELB problem, the ELB just forwards the HTTP requests. It's also not an EC2 problem since EC2 doesn't operate on HTTP level.

The redirects are either caused by
- your nginx server
- your magento installation

Typically, ssl redirect behaviour is configured on web server level.

There are no redirects present in the nginx config snippet you shared. You didn't share the entire config file, so look for redirects or 301's or 302's in your nginx config file. Also investige other nginx config files and .htaccess files in your magento installation folder.

I'm not familiar with Magento, but Magento could also cause the http(s) redirects.
Make sure you set the 'outside' url (the one that is mapped to the ELB) as your base url, as this will be the base url from the end users' point of view.

On https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_ssl.htm, you can find instructions for configuring Magento for SSL. It might be worth the try to set the base URL to http:// and activate the 'secure urls' options.